# WANTED Two independent instances of same user control as TabItem content (section "WPF is disrespecting my code")

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, tabcontrol

[image: WPF TabControl with two user controls]

Uncheck the checked one, select tab "Header B" and you'll see: the unchecking has been reflected.

How can WPF think I want one instance if I place two user controls and name them differently?

WPF is driving me mad over time.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<!-- The silver price is currently high? I don't care. -->
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Silver" Title="MainWindow" FontSize="14" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Height="300" Width="700" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=_btCancel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" Grid.Row="0" >
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabItem x:Name="_tabItem_A" Header="Header A">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <UserControls:UserControl_1 x:Name="_userControl_A" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="_tabItem_B" Header="Header B">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <UserControls:UserControl_1 x:Name="_userControl_B" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Name="_btCancel" Grid.Row="1" Content="   Cancel   " Margin="0,10,0,10" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsCancel="True" Click="_btCancel_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            List<_ListViewItem> listViewItems = new List<_ListViewItem>();
            listViewItems.Add(new _ListViewItem() { _IsActive = false, _Text = "Text 1" });
            listViewItems.Add(new _ListViewItem() { _IsActive = true, _Text = "Text 2" });
            listViewItems.Add(new _ListViewItem() { _IsActive = false, _Text = "Text 3" });

            Application.Current.Resources.Add("_xamlReference_listViewContent", listViewItems);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void _btCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public class _ListViewItem
    {
        public bool _IsActive { get; set; }
        public string _Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UserControl_1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl_1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="_collectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource _xamlReference_listViewContent}}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="_grid">
        <ListView x:Name="_lv" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _collectionViewSource}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="70">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <Label Content="Active" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=_IsActive}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="130">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <Label Content="Interval" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=_Text}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="80" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl_1.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class UserControl_1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl_1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- These brute force statements do not help: -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:UserControl_1}" x:Shared="False" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" x:Shared="False" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Did you look at [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xshared-attribute) and try to set it to `false`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Please look at the final peace of code.

Comment: I believe, you should use it in `UserControl` declaration

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I tried it, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that both `UserControls` are using the same `List<_ListViewItem>` as their resource in this code:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="_collectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource _xamlReference_listViewContent}}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

when you do this the `Checkbox` on both controls is bound to the same `_IsActive` property of the same object, so changing one will change the other. One way to fix this (see comments) is to set the binding on the check box to `OneWay` like this:

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=_IsActive, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: The same item source is intended, I want to be able to filter each ListView differently.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. bost `listview` are changing the same objects, so of course the changes go from one to the other

Comment: The objects should not be changed by a ListView, I only want two different independent (and later filtered) views, therefore I'm using a one way binding for the ListViews (one way from source).

Comment: You onlt did one way binding on `itemsource` try doing it on the `checkbox` itself:  `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=_IsActive, Mode=OneWay}" />`

Comment: Wouldn't doing it in `OneWay` mode prevent him from changing the checkbox?

Comment: @EfraimNewman: If you shift your last comment into your answer I can mark it as solution. Your proposal seems to be the only necessary correction since I have found out that the following operations on one ListView do not affect the second one: changing a column width, filtering the items, sorting the items by the values of a column. So the ListViews seem indeed to be two instances.

Answer (score 0):

Use MVVM pattern. Have two view-models (one for each tab) that share the state that's related to the checking of the checkboxes and bind the `TabItem` `DataContext` to these view-models.

Generally speaking you should avoid WPF magic when you can and use bindings/view-models to solve your problems.

Comment: Since I never have worked with MVVM I would need a full-code-ready-to-run-solution (and future newbies too).